# Function of に in 怒るに怒れない

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, particle-に, nominalization, zero-particle

In the book I'm reading, I came across the following sentence:

> あたしは[怒]{おこ}るに[怒]{おこ}れなくなった。 <sub>*(furigana added by me)*</sub>

My translation is something like "I couldn't stay angry [at him]".  ("My anger melted away.")

I don't actually understand the grammar, though.  The phrase 「怒るに怒れない」 has what appears to be particle-に following the dictionary form of a verb.  It sounds contrastive.  I can't seem to find this pattern in my dictionaries, though, so I feel unsure.

I'm interpreting it as 「怒る(の)に怒れない」, with a [zero-nominalizer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/zero-nominalisation-why-and-when) after the verb.  Is this correct?

Is this a set phrase preserving old grammar of some kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pattern that means "even if I wanted to V, I cannot V" or "no matter what, I cannot V". As such, in your sentence, it means " I could not get mad even if I wanted to.".

As for the grammar, this is a conjunctive particle (接続助詞). Rather than attaching to the "dictionary form" (終止形), though, it attaches to the attributive (連体形). That is why there is no need for a (zero-) nominalizer.