# Difference between Ｖるのにともなって and Ｖるにともなって?

Tags: grammar, nuances

I've been trying to work out the usage of にともなう, にともなって, and so on, but am having difficulty understanding the difference between placing the particle の after a verb and before にともなう. One grammar resource that I have only gives the usage with の as examples, while another only gives the usage without it as examples.

The first gives as an example: マラソン大会が行われるのに伴って、この道路は通行止めになります。

The second gives as an example: 秋が深まるにともなって、山の紅葉が進む。

Is there a general rule for when to use each of these patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particle に does not usually readily take on a postposition to a verb. That is why the nominaliser の comes in to "rescue" the situation. Then as the structure becomes formed, the nominalisation is implicitly understood and forms the zero-nominalised form without the の.

Zero-nominalisation is when nominalisation occurs without an overt particle.

If you have A Dictionary of Intermediate Japanese Grammar, I think you can refer to page 291. There is a similar situation with には and のには. The dictionary notes that there is no difference between them.

Consider:

> - It takes a considerable amount of time in order to learn Japanese
> - 日本語を習うのにはかなりの時間がかかる (with overt nominalisation)
> - 日本語を習うにはかなりの時間がかかる (zero-nominalisation)

The meaning is the same for both of them.

Comment: I think Dono explained it differently [here](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/9760/1478).  If I understand correctly, you can analyze this by saying the `に` version is attaching to the 連体形, and the `のに` version is attaching to the 終止形.