# Meaning of verb+となる

Tags: grammar, particle-と

> ところが、引き返す**となったとたん**、痛みがましてきた。
>   However, just as it became *time to* go back, the pain increased still further.

I don't understand the grammar of the part in bold. My translation is a best guess.

I'm familiar with the use of とたん to mean 'just as', and なる to mean 'become', but I don't know any grammar where と+なる can attach to a verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this 引き返す is a case of zero-nominalization (discussed here: [Zero-nominalisation - Why and When?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/zero-nominalisation-why-and-when)).

This means that it works, against all appearances, as a noun phrase, and is part of  the familiar construction "NP + と + なる" ("become NP").

Hence "**引き返す**となったとたん" more or less equals "as soon as [it] became **that [I'm] going back**". (I'm trying to come up with a natural translation in context but keep drawing a blank.)

Whereas the parallel of "it became **time** to go back" would be "引き返す**時**に/となった".

Answer (score 3):

Your translation is correct. As for the +となる part, allow me to explain:

Normally, when something becomes something, normally you'd see +になる.

However, using +となる implies a finality, as in having FINALLY become that stage of change.

The translation might become more correct if it were: "However, just as it **ultimately** became time to go back, the pain increased still further."

...or something to that extent. Hope this helps!

Comment: Not sure if this answer is correct or not but here must be something related to 〜となる vs. 〜になる https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/739/19206

Comment: yes, +になる shows the direction of change, where +となる shows the end result of a change, thus the finality. in a sense, it's a discrete change and not an ongoing change. for example, if the time were approaching, that'd be a +になる, but when the time finally arrives, +となる expresses that better. at least, that's how I learned it!